# Tensorflow: Storing in models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to tf and i want to store the activation in the model.

I am trying to build an image classifier and while predicting one image using `sess.run(activation,feed_dict={X:npArray})`.

How do I store the activation and X in the model and restore them back?

I am using something like this for restoring

```
y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0')
X = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
```

and then using

```
output_label = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: npArray})
```

for predicting the label of the class but no matter what the npArray input is, the output_label doesn't change. If even the stored model changes, the output_label does not change. This can mean that the variable y_pred and placeholder X are not

> 1. either stored properly in the model; or
> 2. they are not restored properly

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It can be from many reasons please provide more details (what is the dependency between y_pred and X? etc)

Comment: y_pred is the output of the activation layer and X is the input image placeholder. The full code is at https://codeshare.io/2jO4oR

Comment: In general the technique you described above should work. If you would like help debugging your specific problem, please provide a complete, minimal, verifiable example rather than linking to your entire code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is the training cost reduced overtime? Can you share a log of the prints form your code?

Comment: Check giving an input from the training dataset and verifying you getting different output.